# Qt - Connecting C++ and QML - ReferenceError: xxx is not defined

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt and am currently trying to connect a c++ part of my program with the qml part. The goal of th connection is to pass the currently selected item of a TreeView to qml (possibly via on_treeView_doubleClicked). Since that didnt work I tried all the suggested connections on here for a very basic programm, but I am always receiving the following error:

`file::/main.qml:10: ReferenceError: test is not defined`

This is the piece of my code regarding the connection:

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit test(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void testFunc();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void test::testFunc()
{
    qDebug() <<  "Hello from C++!";
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
test testObj;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/main.qml"));

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("test", &testObj);
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Item {
    Timer{
        id: timer
        interval: 1000; running: true; repeat:true
        onTriggered:{
            console.log("ex")
            test.testFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

I would be really thankful for any help (not only for the simple programm, but possibly for passing the currently selected item of my treeView). I know there a a couple suggestions in other threads, but they dont seem to work for me, so please dont mark this as duplicate.

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Comment: `qmlRegisterType<test>("com.mycompany.testing", 1, 0, "test");` See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html). Note that in your case also `qmlRegisterSingletonType` is needed (you are exposing some object to QML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 main errors:

- If you are going to use a .qml from a qresource you should not use `QUrl::fromLocalFile()` since the qresource is not a local file but virtual.
- `testObj` is a local variable so it will be eliminated as soon as the function where it was created is finished, one solution is to make `testObj` a member of the class.
- And for the last one, the main error, `QQuickWidget` already has a `QQmlEngine`, you do not have to create another one.

---

***.h**

```
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
test testObj;
```

***.cpp**

```
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
ui->quickWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("test", &testObj);
```

My full test can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51635985)